# How can I get my mouse cursor to not keep jumping around?

Tags: mouse, solaris-10, sunray

I'm using a pair of SunRay 2 thin-clients in a dual-head configuration (via SRSS, with Xinerama).  On the secondary display, the mouse cursor will sometimes decide to jump to the upper left corner of the screen while I'm moving it (very rarely it will jump to other locations).  While not moving, it stays in place just fine.  However, while in motion it will do that "warp somewhere else" type action.  Does not happen when the cursor is on the primary screen.  I'm able to replicate the problem on another Solaris server, with SunRay 1g thin-clients at another location too!

Comment: Propose moving to superUser

Comment: SuperUser experience with thin clients is likely to be more limited.

Comment: An interesting sidenote is that it occurs much more frequently when there's a lot of screen updates going on (especially Flash items in a browser.  The particular browser doesn't seem to matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks DoxJeremy for hooking me up with the info!  Here's the answer he pointed me at:

- ottomeister from the Oracle forums reports that a fix for this is going into the next software release/patch.
- cniederh also from the Oracle forums tells us that:

  A workaround to fix the jumping effect is to use Xsun instead of Xnewt as default Xserver for the Sunray DTUs:

  utxconfig -b Xsun -a

  either as root (with -a for all sessions) or without -a for the current session.

  Logout/Login and the jumping mouse effect is gone.